# Java reading serialized in objects from file into an arrayList

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, io

I'm attempting to read a file that contains serialized objects of type Contact into an ArrayList contactsCollection.  The issue I'm having is that the objects Contact never get added into the ArrayList.

```
try
{
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("contactList.dat"));
    Contact temp;
    while (in.available()!=0)
    {
        temp = (Contact)in.readObject();
        contactsCollection.add(temp);

    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Then in.available() was 0, are you sure you have Contacts in that file?

Comment: I agree with @greedybuddha, print something out just after you assign temp to make sure temp is not null, that you are getting there, and that you have the right data.

Comment: Can you try to debug and see the execution flow.

Comment: `in.available() != 0` is not a valid test for end of stream.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known behaviour of ObjectInputStream.available, it always returns 0, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4954570. Instead, you can read objects from file until EOFException is thrown, catch it and break.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you entire approach is wrong: You should serialize the *List*, not each object.

All List implementations are `Serializable`. Just create the list, add your onjbects and serialize the list - the objects in it will be serialized too (if they implement `Serializable`, which obviuosly your do).

Then to deserialize, simply read in the object, and voila - you have a list with all our objects added in already.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList`s are `Serializable` provided their contents are.  If the code that stores the `Contact`s to the stream has them in an `ArrayList`, just read the list in all at once.

If not, you probably want to have the code storing the `Contact`s store the length first:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("contactList.dat"),
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
    int size = in.readInt();
    for (final int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        contacts.add((Contact) in.readObject());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Mixing `available` and `readObject` is unwise; `available` would tell how many bytes are available without causing the stream to block, except that Evegniy's comment applies.  Those bytes may not represent a complete object.

If you can't get the code writing to the stream to put the size in first, you'll simply have to loop through and depend on the fact that an `EOFException` is an `IOException`.